# Android how to create bitmap image with correct orientation?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-image, google-mlkit

I am working on a project that uses mlkit to detect id card inside an image. The output is a cropped image that has only the id card.
When I create an input bitmap from the given image file's uri, the input bitmap is in wrong orientation.

```kotlin
var inputBitmapWithWrongOrientation1: Bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(requireContext().contentResolver, inputUri)
// var inputBitmapWithWrongOrientation2: Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoFile.path)
```

From what I gather, the input file is saved with correct orientation (ie, 0 degree). So whatever you do (`ExifInterFace`, `MediaStore contentresolver query`) they return 0 degree. MlKit reads input uri and processes everything with correct orientation. So detectedObject.boundaryBox is correct. But inputBitmapWithWrongOrientation1 is in wrong orientation (90 or 270 degree). So trying to crop inputBitmapWithWrongOrientation1 with that boundaryBox crops wrong part of the image.

As a result, the `inputBitmapWithWrongOrientation1` is always in wrong orientation( 90 degree or 270 degree orientation).

How can I get the inputBitmap with correct orientation?
The relevant code segment:

```kotlin
  val inputBitmap: Bitmap = getBitmapWithCorrectOrientation(inputUri) // <-- what should be this?


  val inputImage: InputImage = InputImage.fromFilePath(contentResolver, inputUri) // for mlkit

        objectDetector.process(inputImage).addOnSuccessListener { detectedObjectsList ->
            Log.e(TAG, "detectedObjectsList.size = ${detectedObjectsList.size}")
            for(detectedObject in detectedObjectsList) {
                val bBox = detectedObject.boundingBox
                val outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(inputBitmap, bBox.left, bBox.top, bBox.width(), bBox.height())
                outputIv.setImageBitmap(outputBitmap)
            }
        }
```

## Edit

I am getting the image uri from CameraX:

```kotlin
        val photoFile = File(requireContext().getExternalFilesDir(""), SimpleDateFormat(FILENAME_FORMAT, Locale.US
        ).format(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg")  // <-- this is the captured image / input image save location

        // create output options object which contains file + metadata
        val outputOptions = ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(photoFile).build()

imageCapture.takePicture(
            outputOptions, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(requireContext()),
object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback{
                override fun onImageSaved(outputFileResults: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {
                    var inputUri = outputFileResults.savedUri
                    // then the rest of the code below

  }
}
// ... ...
)
```

As you can see, the picture is a `.jpg` file that is saved in `photoFile`. CameraX saves the photo in this. I have checked that the picture is taked properly.

Comment: `When I create an input bitmap from the given image file's uri, ` How did you get that file/uri to begin with? How would it be 'given'? And what kind of file is it?

Comment: I get it from CameraX. That is, CameraX captures an image, then you get it in the callback. I'll update the question.

Comment: The file is an image file with extension ".jpg"

Comment: Yes but you save some content in a file which you give a file name with extension .jpg. But is it a .jpg file? I mean i can save a pdf or word document too with extension .jpg. Further if it is indeed a jpg file you should be able to use ExifInterface on photoFile.getAbsolutePath() to get the orientation.

Comment: okay, I'll check that

Comment: Can you give an example of the values of photoFile.getAbsolutePath() and inputUri.toString()?

Comment: ```photoFile.absolutePath = /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/myapp.one/files/2021-05-03-10-50-30-868.jpg
inputUri.toString = file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/myapp.one/files/2021-05-03-10-50-30-868.jpg```

Comment: and you were right. it is not `jpg`, but it is a `jpeg` file (I downloaded the photo on pc and checked image property)

Comment: I see no difference between .jpg and .jpeg.